# USB hard drive on OTG not mounted in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, usb, usb-otg

I am trying to mount a USB hard drive (Seagate Backup Plus) via the USB OTG port of my Wandboard on Arch Linux ARM. When I plug in the drive the pilot light flashes several times and Arch Linux finds the device, but finds it as a USB hub:

```
[ 1912.431400] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[ 1912.452800] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[ 1912.458503] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.08
[ 1912.466803] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[ 1912.474060] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[ 1912.478967] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.8.7-1-ARCH ehci_hcd
[ 1912.484916] usb usb1: SerialNumber: ci_hdrc.0
[ 1912.489891] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1912.493807] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
```

Is there a way I can have Linux recognize the HDD as a block device so that I can then mount it?

I would be happy to supply any further information.
TIA
Les

---

Progress report:
In continuing my research I find that the g_mass_storage module
is in my device tree. Am I right in assuming that I wouldn't need to recompile Arch ARM in order to use the USB HDD as a storage device, since I already have this module? However I would need help with how to go about enabling the module at boot time in order to be able to mount the HDD.
Below is the output of **modinfo** on the module:

```
[alarm@alarm ~]$ modinfo g_mass_storage
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.7-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/legacy/g_mas                    s_storage.ko.gz
license:        GPL
author:         Michal Nazarewicz
description:    Mass Storage Gadget
depends:        usb_f_mass_storage,libcomposite
intree:         Y
name:           g_mass_storage
vermagic:       5.8.7-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8
parm:           idVendor:USB Vendor ID (ushort)
parm:           idProduct:USB Product ID (ushort)
parm:           bcdDevice:USB Device version (BCD) (ushort)
parm:           iSerialNumber:SerialNumber string (charp)
parm:           iManufacturer:USB Manufacturer string (charp)
parm:           iProduct:USB Product string (charp)
parm:           file:names of backing files or devices (array of charp)
parm:           ro:true to force read-only (array of bool)
parm:           removable:true to simulate removable media (array of bool)
parm:           cdrom:true to simulate CD-ROM instead of disk (array of bool)
parm:           nofua:true to ignore SCSI WRITE(10,12) FUA bit (array of bool)
parm:           luns:number of LUNs (uint)
parm:           stall:false to prevent bulk stalls (bool)
``
```

Comment: Thanks, Oskar, for your good suggestion.